# :echo inside :inorea not working

Tags: opengl, vim

I'm trying to use vim plugin [hints_opengl.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/hints_opengl.vim/blob/master/ftplugin/hints_opengl.vim), but it is not working as intended. If you look at the plugin's code, it is supposed to `:echo` some text using `:inorea` call like this:

```
inorea glEnd glEnd<c-o>:echoh HintHL<Bar>echo "void glEnd(void)"<Bar>echoh None<cr>
```

However for me it doesn't echo anything. I tried to define some `inorea`s with `:echo` command like this:

```
inorea hhh hhh<c-o>:echo "hello"<cr>
```

But those didn't work either. However doing `<c-o>:echo "something"` manually during typing in insert mode works fine. What should I do then to properly echo text with `:inorea`? How do I get this plugin to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see the messages in insert mode because the default height of the command-line is one, and the `-- INSERT --` immediately overwrites your message.

Either increase the height:

```
:set cmdheight=2
```

or turn off the display of the current mode:

```
:set noshowmode
```